# Assigning variables to columns with 20 rows and subtracting them in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in excel vba. I am writing a code where want to store the values of 20 rows on a column in a variable and similarly another set of values from 20 rows in another variable. Then I want to subtract one from the other and store in another variable (eg. A). This procedure I will repeat for 3 more times with different sets of data and will end up with 4 variables (eg. A, B, C, D).  Finally, I want to find the maximum of all the 4 variables and assign the values into a column.

[image]

(The maximum values I want to put in delE column)

I have tried this as presented below. But it did not work. It erases the values of all the columns. I am attaching the code here. Can you please help me?

```
Sub span()
    Dim I0 As Variant
    Dim T1 As Variant
    Dim I1 As Variant
    Dim T2 As Variant
    Dim I2 As Variant
    Dim A  As Variant
    Dim B  As Variant
    Dim C  As Variant
    Dim D  As Variant
    Dim G  As Variant

    G = Range("G5").Value - Range("C5").Value

     Range("C5:C25").Value = I0
     Range("D5:D25").Value = T1
     Range("E5:E25").Value = I1
     Range("F5:F25").Value = T2
     Range("G5:G25").Value = I2
     A = I2 - I0
     B = T2 - I0
     C = T2 - I1
     D = T1 - I1 + G

    Range("H5:H25").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(A, B, C, D)
End Sub
```

Comment: C5:C25 is **21** rows.

Comment: You don't need VBA for this, you can use formulas.

Comment: Range("C5:C25").Value = I0 means that you write from the variable IO (value=0) to the Range. You cannot add and subtract vectors in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You already have this you can use the `rows` `row` and `columns` `column` from a range.

A range can go straight into an array, which has indexed values, and 
Using an array is a little quicker.

```
Sub aTest()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim a() As Variant

Set r = Range("a1:d20")
a = r.Value

For x = 1 To UBound(a)

    For t = 1 To r.Columns.Count

        Debug.Print "Row " & x & " Value " & t & " " & a(x, t)

    Next t

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, like this, if I set another variable b(y, w) then can I subtract a from b? I tried but couldn't do that.

Comment: So row 1 column 4-row 1 column 3, would be `result=a(1, 4)-a(1, 3)`  you can use variables etc, for the numbers